# How to get request parameters using ServletMultipartRequest

Tags: java, html, jsp

Long story short - I have fileUploader.jsp which referees to itself when submit button is clicked and does some file processing after that.

My problem is that I'm getting NULL's when trying to access some request parameters, here is the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name=uploadSapFile  action="fileUploader.jsp" method="POST">     
           <table>               
              <tr><td>Select file to process:</td></tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>File:</td>
                   <td><input type="file" name="fileName" size=50></td></tr>      
              <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="action" value="Process"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="PROCESS"></td>
              </tr>
           </table> 
        </form>

        <%
        String action = null;
        String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
        File file = null;

        try {

            if (referrer.indexOf("fileUploader.jsp") != -1)  { 

                MultipartRequest parser = new ServletMultipartRequest(request, "fileLocation", 10000000);
                action = parser.getURLParameter("action"); // THIS PARAMETER IS NULL
                file = parser.getFile("fileName");

                // Some file processing ... (not relevant to the problem) 

        finally {

            if (file != null) {
                file.delete();          
            } 
        }%>
   </body>
</html>
```

P.S. However I'm getting the file and able to process is without problems, it's just other parameter from the same from that I'm struggling with.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

UPDATE: Send the parameter value as hidden field and it worked, edited code as well

Comment: What do you expect as value of parser.getURLParameter("action")? I guess "Process" ?

Comment: If I uderstand correctly you send you request on http://yourserver.com/bla/fileUploader.jsp. There no URL parameters. If you want get it, it shold be http://yourserver.com/bla/fileUploader.jsp?action=Process, or you can put hide parameter in you form and get it as POST parameter.

Comment: You right, thanks. Did that as a hidden field, just for the interest - is there no other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put hide parameter in you form and get it as POST parameter in java code. As far as i know this is the only one solution for uploading file and passing parameter.